# I have got this error while running non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, compiler-errors

Error:(51) Error parsing XML: no element found
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\tariq ziad\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

in my content main file, there is an error showing, "unexpected end of file" last thing is a button. I dont know whats missing? Please someone check it out.

Comment: Check your XML files and verify they are well formed

Comment: Perhaps you could include some code snippet of your XML files...

Answer (score 0):

It's general problem to me also. It happens when the external device is not able to update your app when you run the app. Try uninstalling the installed app and install again. If problem persist please provide full `logcat` result.